# WPF Merge parent and child context menus

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

My **ListView** has **ContextMenu** with some options. There are some **TextBlocks** inside **ListView**  with their own **ContextMenus**, when I right click on **TextBlock**, only **TextBlock's ContextMenu** appears. How can I show **ListView** options merged with **TextBlock** options?

**Code Example:**

```xaml
<ListView>
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="List option"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
    <ListViewItem>
        <TextBlock Text="Text">
            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="TextBlock option"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock>
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Why don't you add ListView's options with TextBlock's options manually in xaml?

Comment: @MuhammadSulaiman because in my real project context menus are dynamic also same textblocks are used in different lists

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right approach, but you can sync the context menu items in the loaded event of the textblocks contextmenu.
You need to build every new context menu item from scratch, you can't just merge them.

```
Private Sub ContextMenu_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim textblockContextmenu As ContextMenu = sender

    For Each item As MenuItem In lst.ContextMenu.Items
        Dim newitem As New MenuItem
        newitem.Header = item.Header
        If Not textblockContextmenu.Items.OfType(Of MenuItem)().Select(Of String)(Function(x) x.Header).Contains(item.Header) Then
            textblockContextmenu.Items.Add(newitem)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried this, but the problem is binding command parameter.